# Rotate a grid inside a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I have the following code,

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[thin,<->] (-4.5,0) -- (4.5,0);
\draw[thin,<->] (0,-4.4) -- (0,4.5);

\clip[draw] circle (4cm);
\draw[step=0.3cm,red,very thin] (-4,-4) grid (3,4);
\draw[step=0.3cm,blue,very thin] (3,-4) grid (4,4);

\draw[thick,-] (3,0.1) -- (3,-0.1) node[anchor=north] {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

What I want to do is rotate the grid but keep the cut exactly on the vertical line (where I marked A).

To rotate, I just add `rotate=20`, and the result is

[image: 2]

But what I would like is for the grid to go to the green line... And I would do the same with the blue grid (at some other angle). The problem is that when I rotate I can't adjust the grid as I want....

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't know how to work with the `clip` command, I wasn't able to solve the problem, now I did.

To get the result, just do the following code,

```
\begin{scope}
    \clip (2.5,-3) rectangle (3,3);
    \clip circle (3cm);
    \draw[rotate=-25,step=0.1cm,red,very thin] (1,-3) grid (3,3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
    \clip (-3,-3) rectangle (2.5,3);
    \clip circle (3cm);
    \draw[rotate=23,step=0.15cm,blue,very thin] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
\end{scope}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: I propose a solution with only one clip.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution with only one clip. With radius and angle and using polar coordinates.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644151/rotate-a-grid-inside-a-circle
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \newcommand{\rayon}{4}
    \newcommand{\ang}{60}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %\draw[help lines](0,0)grid(5,5);
    \node at (\ang:\rayon) (B) {$\bullet$};
    \node[above] at(B){$B$};
    \node at (-\ang:\rayon) (C) {$\bullet$};
    \node[below] at(C){$C$};

    \begin{scope}
    \clip[draw] (B)arc [start angle=\ang, end angle=360-\ang, radius=\rayon]--cycle;
    \draw[rotate=25,step=0.3cm,red,very thin] (-2\rayon,-2\rayon) grid (2\rayon,2\rayon);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
    \clip[draw] (B)arc [start angle=\ang, end angle=-\ang, radius=\rayon]--cycle;
    \draw[rotate=-25,step=0.3cm,blue,very thin] (-2\rayon,-2\rayon) grid (2\rayon,2\rayon);
    \end{scope}

    \draw [green!70,very thick](B)--(C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. When I posted it I didn't realize I could work with the `clip`, but I didn't delete it, as someone might provide a better solution.